# Google Maps keep crashing for unknow reason iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

i'm using a google maps in my project first i made a separated demo for it and it works fine then i made the same steps again in my actual project and from there it keep crashes and give me the following error

-[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15dbfc00'

and also

ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection error 101.)"

i added -ObjC and -all_load too and nothing happened also created a new app in google APIs Console and still nothing happening and it keep crashes

so please if anyone can help me thanks a lot

```
[super viewDidLoad];
self.gMapView.delegate = self;

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:1.285
                                                            longitude:103.848
                                                                 zoom:12];
    self.gMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    self.view = self.gMapView;
```

and that's my app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

{

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyBPEpHefI5yHqkwWNR0G6omzSOwcKxb5ag"];


UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor colorWithRed:60.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.0];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:tintcolor];

// 1
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

// 2
[[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

// 3
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;

// 4
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-56097385-1"];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
[FBLoginView class];
UIViewController * initViewController;
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
storageManager = [[StorageManager alloc] init];
NSString * value = [storageManager stringFromUserDeafultsUsignKey:STORAGE_KEY_SESSIONID];
NSLog(@"%@", value);
if(value == nil ){
    initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LunchViewController"];
        [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
}else{
    initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenuViewController"];
        [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
}


return YES;
```

}

i'm using 1.9 googlemaps sdk and used before it 1.8 and was the same error and my target is iOS 7 and test it over iphone 7.1 and simulator

Comment: do you have the google api access token/ access key?

Comment: @NorthBlast yes i have it AIzaSyBPEpHefI5yHqkwWNR0G6omzSOwcKxb5ag and it is already added to my app delegate  btw im using lots of APis and SDK in my app like Facebook one incase you know if that may cause such an error thanks

Comment: You should not publicly post your API key!

Comment: Is your -ObjC flag set in your target or project? It should be on the project's build settings.

Comment: @Kerni it's okay its for testing only but thanks a lot for the advice

Comment: @KerrM in project when i add it to the target i got 17 linker errors and also the doc says it should be in the project

Comment: @ahmedHegazi - that's what I said: the objc flag should be added to the *project* build settings, _not_ the target build settings

Comment: @KerrM that's what i did and keep give me the error up there in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake was adding -ObjC in project not in the target